# Can derived classes have more than one pointer to a virtual table?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable, memory-layout, vptr

I am watching the BackToBasics talk: [Virtual Dispatch and Its Alternatives](https://youtu.be/jBnIMEb2GhA?t=573) 
 from CppCon2019. The presenter says and the slide shows (assuming I haven't misunderstood) that a derived class inherits a vtable pointer from the base class and additionally has its own vptr.

Of course, technically this isn't mandated by the standard but I am getting myself a bit confused and my  experiments with sizeof() also seem to imply there should only need to be one pointer. Please can someone clarify if there are any situations where multiple vptrs are needed?

Thanks

P.S. Just to be clear, in this context we are considering the more common public inheritance and not virtual or multiple inheritance (the presenter explicitly mentions this in an earlier part of the talk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The a vtable contains the address of each virtual function for the class at a known offset.

[Remark: In practice unlike a regular class, vtables have members at negative offset, much like a pointer in a the middle of a array. That is just a convention that doesn't change implementation freedom much. Anyway the only issue is that the placement of an information in a vtable is legislated by a convention (the ABI) and compilers by following the same one produce compatible code for polymorphic classes.]

What happens when you have additional functions in a derived class? (not just the functions "inherited" from the base class)

Once you accept the idea that a pointer to a structure both points to the whole object and to its first member, you have the idea that a pointer to derived class points to a base class that is appropriately located at offset zero. So you can have **the exact same pointer value, as represented as a `void*`, that can be used alternatively for a derived object or a base under this convention for single inheritance**.

Now you can apply that to any data structure and even to a vtable which is really not a table (array of elements of the same type, or values that can be interpreted in the same way) but a record (of objects of unrelated type or meaning); you can see that a vtable for such derived class can just be derived from the vtable of its unique base in the exact same way.

(Note that if you compile C++ to C, you might run into type aliasing rules when you do such things. Of course assembly has no such problem, nor naively compiled "high level assembler" C.)

So for single inheritance the base is integrated and optimized into the derived class:

- for data members of the instance (of a class type)
- and for the virtual functions members, that is the data members of the vtable (or members of the meta class if you imagine one).

Note that *placing the base at offset zero allows you to place vtable base at zero offset*, which in turn allows you to use the same vptr but does not imply it; conversely sharing the vptr with a base implies that the base vtable is at offset zero (vtable layout = meta class level) so the base must be at offset zero (data members layout = class level).

And multiple inheritance is actually single inheritance plus, as one class is always treated as privileged: it is placed at offset zero so the pointers are the same, so the vtable can be placed at offset zero (because the pointers are the same); others bases, not so.

As we see, all but one of the inherited polymorphic classes are placed at a non zero offset in multiple inheritance. Each one carries an additional "inherited" vptr in the derived class; that (hidden) pointer member must be correctly filled by any derived constructor.

**These additional vptr are for base classes that occur at non zero offset**, so a pointer to an inherited base must be adjusted (add a positive constant to convert to base pointer, remove it to convert back). That a compiler needs to produce code to perform an implicit conversion is a trivial remark (converting an integer to a floating point type is a much more involved task); but here the conversion of `this` is between a function call on a given base type and landing in the function that is an overrider in a base or derived class: the difference is that **adjustment depends on function overriding which is only known for a class** (an instance of a meta type). So *the vptr needs to point to distinct vtable information*: one that knows how to deal with these base to derived pointer conversions.

As instances of the "meta type", vtables have all the information to do all pointers adjustment automatically. (These depend on the specific class types involved, and on no other factor.)

So at implementation level, the two types of inheritances are:

- zero offset inheritance; sharing the vptr; called a primary base class in some vtable and ABI descriptions;
- arbitrary offset inheritance; having another vptr; called secondary base class.

This is for the basic stuff. Virtual inheritance is a lot more subtle at the implementation level, and even the concept of primary isn't so clear, as virtual bases can be "primary" of a derived class only in some more derived classes!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I understanding correctly that you are saying that there will be one vptr per inheritance chain. So, if a ptr is 8 bytes,  the extra memory cost will be 8 bytes for single inheritance chain (no matter how deep), 16 bytes if I do multiple inherit from 2 chains etc?

Comment: @CanISleepYet That's one per chain involving a polymorphic base; bases w/o virtuals don't count; also the counting of "chains" is different for virtual bases. "_8 bytes for single inheritance chain (no matter how deep)_" Exactly depth has no size cost.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now I am slightly confused because the way that I understood the other answer it seems like they contradict each other? (slightly in the case of multiple inheritance)

Comment: @CanISleepYet I don't think there was a contradiction as David Schwartz was talking about MI.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have two classes, each with at least one virtual function, `Possession` and `Vehicle`. To invoke those virtual functions for an instance of a derived class of either of those, a pointer to a virtual table is needed. Since these two classes are independent, their virtual tables will be completely different.

Now imagine that `OwnedVehicle` derives from both `Possession` and `Vehicle`. To call a virtual function in `Possession` for an instance of `OwnedVehicle` requires a pointer to a virtual function table of the type required by `Possession`. Similarly, to call a virtual function in `Vehicle` for an instance of `OwnedVehicle` requires a pointer to a virtual function table of the type required by `Vehicle`.

Typical implementations handle this by building a virtual function table for `OwnedVehicle` that contains one part for `OwnedVehicle` virtual functions (if any), one for `Vehicle` virtual functions and one for `Possession` virtual functions. Then, when calling a virtual function from a pointer to an object of a different type, all that the compiler has to do is apply an applicable delta to the virtual function table pointer to point to the correct part of it.

While the multiple inheritance case is more complex, the same occurs with just single inheritance. The virtual function table for `OwnedVehicle` contains inside it a virtual function table for `Vehicle` and would do so even if `Possession` were not involved.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Am I correct to take away from your answer that there will only ever be one virtual table pointer no matter how deep the inheritance chain and even if multiple inheritance is involved. The compiler will just create a composite vtable for every level of the hierarchy (where one is required)?

Comment: Apologies, after reading the other answer I realised that I have probably misunderstood the part about multiple inheritance here.

Comment: @CanISleepYet There will be one big vtable, because that's what you need for classes derived from this class. But the big vtable will consist of several smaller vtables, one for each class this class is derived from that has at least one virtual function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Do you agree that conceptually only the small vtables exist and the "big" table is just a colocation w/o any essential layout invariant?

Comment: @curiousguy No. If that were true, how could you derive from the class? Every class has a vtable layout that must be adhered to by all derived classes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree that every vtable is abstractly a set of axioms that derived classes must follow. What I don't get is your "big vtable" thing and what it does above what the "small vtables" do.

Comment: @curiousguy The big vtable is used to pass to virtual functions in this class. The small vables are used to pass to virtual functions in derived classes. If something is derived from class A, which is derived from B and C, there must be an instance of B's vtable and C's vtable for class A. If D is derived from A, it needs a big vtable (containing both the B and C vtables for D) to pass to functions defined in class A).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So you are saying that the virtual functions of all bases can be accessed from just one vptr?

Comment: @curiousguy Yes, and that's what gets passed to a virtual function defined in that very class. The table for a virtual function defined in one of its bases can be a subset of that big table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202842/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-david-schwartz).